# JavaFX timer thread issues

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

I have been trying to create a timer using JavaFX with scenebuilder, however I have been having some issues with creating threads. Whenever I hit the start button the application lags behind and never really updates the text. I have been trying to use `Platform.runLater()`, but as mentioned above everything lags behind and as a result .

Here are the methods controlling the timer, linked to specific buttons on the FXML file:

```
    @FXML
private void startTimer(){
    System.out.println("started");
    stopWatch.startTimer();

}

@FXML
private void pauseTimer(){
    stopWatch.pauseTimer(); 
}

@FXML
private void stopTimer(){
    System.out.println("stopped");
    stopWatch.stopTimer();
}

@FXML
public void updateTimer(long dT){

    //System.out.println(((dT/6000)%1000)+":"+String.valueOf((dT/1000)%1000)+","+String.valueOf((dT)%1000));
    Platform.runLater(() ->{
        timer.setText(String.valueOf(dT/1000) );
    }); 
}
```

And here is the StopWatch.java class:

```
package sled.timer.address.model;

import sled.timer.address.view.PersonOverviewController;

public class StopWatch implements Runnable{

private Thread runThread; 
public boolean running = false; 
public boolean paused = false; 


private long summedTime = 0; 

PersonOverviewController personOverviewController; 

String time = ""; 

public void count(){

}
public StopWatch(PersonOverviewController personOverviewController){
    this.personOverviewController = personOverviewController; 

}
public void startTimer(){
    running  = true; 
    paused = false; 

    runThread = new Thread(this); 
    runThread.start(); 
}

public void pauseTimer(){
    paused = true; 
}

public void stopTimer(){
    running = false; 
    paused = false; 
}
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    while(running && !paused){
        personOverviewController.updateTimer(summedTime + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    }
    if(paused)
        summedTime += System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime; 

    else 
        summedTime = 0; 

}

public long getSummedTime(){
    return summedTime; 
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You do not limit the update frequency of your thread. This way this way you post so many `Runable`s for the application thread to execute, that there is little time to do the event handling and layouting which makes your application behave this way.

Furthermore you do not synchronize the accesses to the boolean flags and do not make them `volatile`, which means value changes do not necessarily become visible to other threads.

Instead you should make sure no more updates are posted until the last `Runnable` has been started:

```
private final Object updaterLock = new Object();
private final boolean updating = false;
private final long value; 

public void updateTimer(long dT) {
    synchronized (updaterLock) {
        value = dT;
        if (!updating) {
           updating = true;
           Platform.runLater(() -> {
               synchronized (updaterLock) {
                   updating = false;
                   timer.setText(Long.toString(value/1000));
               }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

```
public class StopWatch implements Runnable{

    ...

    public volatile boolean running = false; 
    public volatile boolean paused = false;
```

---

However consider using [the `AnimationTimer` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/animation/AnimationTimer.html) to do the updates. The update frequency of this class is limited.